# How to send real output without headers to file in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, logging

I have a PowerShell script where I use `Add-Content` to send `$output` to `log.txt`. `$output` is generated as `Test-Connection nrk.no -count 1` (nrk.no is a random website I trust will remain up most of the time). I now get a long string: `\\NOTREALNAME\root\cimv2:Win32_PingStatus.Address="nrk.no",BufferSize=32,NoFragmentation=false,RecordRoute=0,ResolveAddressNames=false,SourceRoute="",SourceRouteType=0,Timeout=4000,TimestampRoute=0,TimeToLive=80,TypeofService=0` . How can I get the long one with hyphens and headers (see below), but remove the header part so that I log the user friendly part of the output but do not get header and then info over and over again in my log file?

"The long one with hyphens and headers":
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by _the long one_ ? Test-Connection outputs **objects** so you can simply use `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'ThePropertyYouNeed' | Add-Content ...`

Comment: Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71422820/edit) with an example of the output you're expecting? "the long one with hyphens and headers, but remove the header part" is not very clear...

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output to `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders` to get table formatted output without the header:

```
Test-Connection nrk.no |Format-Table -HideTableHeaders |Out-String -Stream |Add-Content log.txt
```

Comment: How can I send it with an extra indent?